# How to increase The maximum size of one packet in MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

**While trying to import full world database to mysql server i have occurred error attached , ** 
 [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAQON.png)
 @Bogir[rus] have found solution for Me but i still want to share how to resolve this problem.

Open mysql shell and enter SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
(where "1073741824" is maximum size in kb)

Answer (score 0):

Open mysql shell and enter SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824; (where "1073741824" is maximum size in kb)